# Notarize an application without installer

Tags: applications, package-management, notarization

I have an application which is distributed without an installer. Just a .zip is given to the users which contains the .app structure of the application. The application is signed with a valid Developer ID and the .zip has been notarized successfully. When I run the security check with the the command `spctl -a -vv -t execute` the response is "accepted". However this doesn't seem to be a valid check because also old version of the application (without notarization) obtain the  same response.

The problem is that when the .zip is downloaded this is flagged with the attribute `com.apple.quarantine` and when the user double click on the .app an error message is shown: *The application MyApp.app can't be opened*.

The only way to run the application is manually remove the flag and set the executable permission to the binary.

1. How can I avoid these manual steps without creating a .pkg of the application ?
2. Why Gatekeeper doesn't trust the application which is signed and notarized ?